# Unable to log in on Chromium

Tags: support, login

I was trying to press the *log in* button on the top of the [math site](http://math.stackexchange.com), and it showed me the “Aw, Snap!” page every time. I tried all alternative sites, including the main login. However, I am still shown the same page with that browser. The incognito mode doesn't work either.

I am using Chromium's version 26.0.1389.0 (177870) but for typing this question out, I have to use IE which I personally don't prefer to use.

Comment: I don't think that version (a dev release) is [supported just yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). (Though I have no idea if that might contribute to the cause) Did you try a regular version?

Comment: @Bart Google Chrome? Yes, it does work on Google Chrome.

Comment: Okay. Then I think the answer is going to be "yeah, we don't support that yet". But I'm sure someone will have a look.

Comment: Using future version of browser is no different than using very old version where it concerns browser support in sites: things might or might not work.

Comment: Related: [How to get more info when the “Aw Snap” screen shows up in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728483/how-to-get-more-info-when-the-aw-snap-screen-shows-up-in-chrome) (and ["Aw, Snap!"](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95669) in Google's help).

Comment: @Arjan I checked out the latter, and I recall doing a browser test on StackExchange where everything was shown okay.